# Check whether a character is an alphabet, digit or special character- PYTHON

Tags: python, if-statement, special-characters, control-flow, alphabet

Ques - Check whether a character is an alphabet, digit or special character

I have written a python code solution and it is working well. But when I input ("@"), I get the output as an alphabet instead of special character. Can someone tell me why and how to solve it for @.

```
inp = input("Enter anything : ")
if inp >= "a" and inp <= "z" or inp >= "A" and inp <= "Z":
   print("input is alphabet")
elif inp>="0":
   print("input is number")
else:
   print("special character")
```

Comment: Python also allows chaining comparisons so you could write `inp >= "a" and inp <= "z"` as `"a" <= inp <= "z"`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just add a special catagory for `special char`

```
import re

inp = input("Enter anything : ")
if inp >= "a" and inp <= "z" or inp >= "A" and inp <= "Z":
   print("input is alphabet")
elif inp>="0" and inp<="9":
   print("input is number")

special_characters = "!@#$%^&*()-+?_=,<>/"
if (any(c in special_characters for c in inp)):
   print("special character")
```

Comment: What about any other special character than the ones you listed explicitly ?

Comment: These are all the special characters that are available in my keyboard...Just want to make it simple...As it is basic question never thought of including `All the special chars` available in the `world`...More importantly I thought if user wants any special chars he can simply add to the string instead of using `else`

Comment: Simple is great, but that's just not covering all the possibilities and is plain bad practice.

Comment: @ljmc The other characters are working totally fine. I'm facing some issue with the @ only

Comment: @Bhargav Can u explain the re module u imported.

Comment: @SolitaryParadise, please have a look at my answer or @j_b’s, it classifies "@" correctly as a special character.

Answer (score 0):

```
elif inp>="0" and inp<="9":
   print("input is number")
```

You need to specify the end for the set of numbers.
Everything else should stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could also utilize Python's String methods `isalpha()` and `isnumeric()`.

```
def get_char():
    """
    Prompt user for character input, or exit if user
    enters more than a single character.
    :return: The user input character.
    """
    inp = input("Enter any character: ")
    if len(inp) != 1: 
        print("Invalid entry, please try again.")
        exit(65) # os.EX_DATAERR, but portable
    return inp

def check_char(inp):
    """
    Inspect character to determine if it is alpha, numeric, or special.
    :param inp: The character to inspect.
    :return: String indicating character identification. 
    """
    if inp.isalpha():
        msg=f'{inp} is alpha char'
    elif inp.isnumeric():
        msg=f'{inp} is numeric char'
    else:
        msg=f'{inp} is special char'
    return msg
    
while True:
    print(check_char(get_char()))
```

Answer (score -1):

You could also rely on the [`string`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html) module and check if a group contains your input:

```py
import string

inp = input("Enter anything : ")

if inp in string.ascii_letters:
    print("input is alphabet")
elif inp in string.digits:
    print("input is number")
else:
    print("special character")
```